# How to correctly compute tangential angle of polynomial?

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

I would like to compute the tangential angle of a polynomial $f(x)$ as shown in this picture:

[image]

Here the red line represents $f(x)$.

According to [this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_angle#Equations) of Wikipedia I can compute the tangential angle as follows

$\varphi = \arctan(f'(x))$

When I try to derive the equation for the tangential angle I end up with the following equation

$\varphi = \arctan(\frac{f(x)}{x})$

Which one is correct?

Comment: $\arctan(f'(x))$ is correct. The gradient of the tangent is $\tan\varphi=f'(x)$.

Comment: Your formula is for the angle between $OP$ and the $x$-axis, where $O$ is the origin.

Comment: Your mistake was in assuming that the point where the tangent line intersects the $x$-axis was the origin. This will rarely be the case. It is some point $(x_0, 0)$ instead, so the formula you should have had is $$\varphi = \arctan\left(\frac{f(x)}{x - x_0}\right)$$ But even then the problem is determining what $x_0$ is. And the only way to do that is to find the slope of the tangent line, which is $f'(x)$, and the one point you already know on that line, $(x,f(x))$, to write an equation for the line and find its $x$-intercept. But doing that arrives right back at $$\varphi = \arctan(f'(x))$$